# Error en funcion que devuelve los catch de funciones async

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Buenas tengo una api en node.js
en la que estoy intentando hacer un middelweare que haga un chaching de los errores de las funciones async en los controladores.

```
controller/ticket.js
```

```html
'use strict'

const Ticket= require('../models/ticket')


const catchAsync = fn => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        fn(req, res, next).catch(next)
    }  
}


exports.getTickets= catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {

    const ticketsList= await Ticket.find()
   
        res.status(200).send({
            status: 'Success',
            code: 200,
            data: balanceSheet,
        })
});
```

El archivo que controla la ruta:

```
routes/ticket.js
```

```html
'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const ticketController = require('../controllers/ticket')

const router = express.Router()


router.get('/tickets/', ticketController.getTikets)

module.exports = router
```

Y esto estaria exportado en el app.js

```html
app.use('/api/v1/data/', dataFrameRoutes)
```

El error que me sale en consola es el siguiente:

```
Error Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
```

Comment: ¿Realmente es necesario hacer tan complejo y abstracto el código? Resulta que eres victima de esa complejidad. ¿Sabes lo que estás pasando como argumento a tu método `get` del enrutador? Si analizas el código a detalle, `getTickets` es el resultado de la llamada a la función `catchAsync`, la cual recibe como parámetro una función tipo `async` anónima, la cual a su vez devuelve otra función anónima que ejecuta tu función `async`. Por lo tanto, estás devolviendo al final una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise).

Comment: ¿Podrías argumentar un poco más cuál es el propósito de lo que deseas lograr? ¿A qué te refieres con *** hacer un middelweare que haga un catching de los errores de las funciones `async` en los controladores**? ¿Acaso no trabajas con el sistema de manejo de errores de Express, tal como lo recomienda la [documentación](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)? Saludos

Comment: La finalidad este código es no tener que estar poniendo todo el rato el try, catch. Es una funcion que hace el catch de cualquier error

Comment: Bien, entiendo tu punto, pero tal vez no comparto tu opinión. Express te permite capturar cualquier tipo de error, sea en funciones asíncronas o no, usando simplemente el llamado a `next(error)`. En cuanto a tu código, tienes un desafío, ya que el enrutador espera una función, y debido a la naturaleza asíncrona de las Promesas (toda función `async` devuelve una Promesa), tu enrutador no está recibiendo una función, sino un objeto. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Asegurate de esto:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('ok')
})
```

Desde la documentación, si el primer argumento es '/tickets/' se tomará como una expresión regular, esta ruta hará match con culaquiera que coincida, y el segundo argumento es una función que devuelva una response. La que esta en tu código no existe  **ticketController.getTikets**

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, pero tu respuesta dice: *no existe ticketController.getTikets*, lo cual es incorrecto, dicho método existe, pero el error es de otro tipo, no porque falte definir el método, sino que el mismo no es una función sino una Promesa. Revisa tu respuesta, porque no es válida en cuanto al problema del OP. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Sé que quizás es muy tarde para que la respuesta sea relevante, pero puede ayudar a alguien que enfrente la misma situación. Ese tipo de error suele ser una llamada a un middleware o un método de controlador que no existe (usualmente una falta de ortografía, una falla o falta en alguna exportación).

En tu caso reemplazando

```
router.get('/tickets/', ticketController.getTikets)
```

por:

```
router.get('/tickets/', ticketController.getTickets)
```

El error desaparece.